# PowerPoint - Create a SmartArt with VBA on an empty slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to populate a PowerPoint presentation with a new smart art on each slide, using VBA. I've come up with a code which basically does that, using:

```
Dim myShape As Shape
Set oSALayout = Application.SmartArtLayouts( _
          "urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2005/8/layout/hChevron3")
Set myShape = curSlide.Shapes.AddSmartArt(oSALayout)
```

The only issue with this code is that, when I use it on a new slide with a basic layout (one Title box and one Content container), the SmartArt is attached to the content box and makes it disappear. The box is technically still in the Shapes list but has its HasSmartArt attribute set to true. So in practice, the SmartArt replaces the box.
However, if I add a bit of text in the content box before running the code, VBA creates a Diagram object for the SmartArt. I tried creating manually a shape but there is no way (as far as I have found) to tell the code which shape to attach to.

Therefore, I would like to know if someone has a solution. In practice, I will mostly use the code on new empty slides, but I would like to be sure that it does not erase any other object without my noticing.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The simplest way around this problem is to check the slide for content placeholder shapes and if one is found, check to see whether it's empty or not. If empty, add some "flag" text that won't normally occur ... @@@I'm A Flag!@@@ for example.  Save a reference to the shape, add your new shape, then delete the text in the placeholder shape (using the saved shape reference).

Comment: I was thinking about that, but was wondering if there was a solution a little bit less "DIY". And if it decides to replace any other object without me noticing, that won't do it.

Comment: This is a programming forum; we're all about DIY. In any case, it's not all that difficult; try it, come back for help if you have trouble getting it working. And the problem will only happen with placeholders, and not even all of them. Never with ordinary shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @steve-rindsberg advice, I add a text flag to all empty placeholders to "protect" them before adding the SmartArt, and remove the text afterwards. (simply testing with `curShape.Type = msoPlaceholder` and `curShape.TextFrame.TextRange = ""`)